# Question about the best way to implement a http stream collector

Tags: azure

We are beginning our migration to Azure. I am trying to implement our Gnip Stream Reader, but was questioning which architecture to use. I would love to go serverless, but not sure if a function would be able to run 24/7 and be stable. Or if there is already a tool like data factory or stream analytics. Also concerned about the cost of a function running 24/7

Comment: If I right understood, you want to host on Azure side some app ingesting data from GNIP by HTTP Streaming protocol and then process this data. I would suggest looking at this scenario: [App Service (Nodejs-app)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/) (it holds on connection with GNIP, receives and passes data further to Azure Event Hub or Azure Service Bus) --> Azure Event Hub / Azure Service Bus --> Azure Stream Analytics.

Comment: It can help you: [Azure Example Scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/example-scenario/#data-scenarios)